# Authentication between a PHP script and firestore

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a backend service running PHP and a database in Firestore. Scripts on PHP is called by callbacks from another services. The services more or less manipulates data and writes it to my Firestore database. During test I have rules set to public but I would like to make this more secure. However I have no idea how to secure the communication between the PHP script and Firetore. I guess one way would to bind on IP but is there more ways? All calls can be secured with secret salt and hash but I guess I would like to make sure its only my script page that is allowed to make the call.

Whats the best way to do this? Today connections are made with simple firebase config.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a PHP Library to securely talk with Firestore from a PHP backend .

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-firestore